# How to check length which can be null

Tags: html, angular, textarea, content-length

I would like to check out my textarea length.
This is my code:

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center textarea-wrapper">
    <p class="mb-1">Additional information to order:</p>
      <textarea class=" additionalInformation justify-content-center" name="additionalInformation"
      value="{{additionalInformation}}" formControlName="additionalInformation" placeholder="text..."
           [maxlength]="maxCharsOfArea"></textarea>

       <span *ngIf="signupForm.controls['additionalInformation'].value.length">
     {{signupForm.controls['additionalInformation'].value.length}} /{{maxCharsOfArea}}</span>
</div>
```

View:

[image]

On Load my page I get error  `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')`

After added any text, everything works perfect.

[image]

What Can I do with this in intialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should be able to use the safe navigation operator `?.` to avoid the error you are receiving.

```
{{signupForm.controls['additionalInformation'].value?.length}} /{{maxCharsOfArea}}
```

https://docs.angular.lat/guide/template-expression-operators#safe-navigation-operator

If you expect that the value remains null after initialization, you could also add a nullish coalescing operator to default your value to 0

```
{{signupForm.controls['additionalInformation'].value?.length ?? 0}} /{{maxCharsOfArea}}
```

Comment: @DaroGawlik wonderful, happy to help! Could you please 'accept' the answer?